# sort words in descending order in a text file

Tags: python, list, file, sorting, puzzle

Im trying to work on a project that generates a crossword puzzle. Its my first time taking/ learning python. So basically I want to first sort the words by length and then take the first word and place it on the grid/board. But when I want to open the file named 'crosswords' it doesnt sort the list of words that the file contains. it prints out this:
None
None
the code below is suppose to sort the words. The file only contains 10 different words. I am not sure if I have the right idea. Any guidance is appreciated! Thanks

```
def sort_words():
   with open('crosswords', 'r') as filename:
        data = [str(i) for i in sorted(filename)]
  
   with open('crosswords', 'w') as filename:
        filename.writelines(data)
        print(data.sort(key=len, reverse=True))

def print_this(var_name) -> None:
    print(var_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     print_this(sort_words())
```

Comment: `sort_words()` doesn't `return` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `sort` method returns `None`. So,

```
print(data.sort(key=len, reverse=True))
```

will print `None`.

To print the result of the sort, you would do either of:

```
data.sort
print(data)
```

or

```
print(sorted(data))
```

Then, in your function `sort_words`, you do not return anything. So, in effect, the line

```
print_this(sort_words())
```

is also asking to print `None`.

You should add

```
return data
```

at the end of your `sort_words` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked but now when it prints it combines 2 words together.